# Searching instructions in OllyDbg

Tags: ollydbg

I have a question about using OllyDbg. Is it possible to search for a part of the code through some command? For example I would like to find this value [ESI + 80] in my exe. It's possible?

Comment: it's exist in ollydbg you can search for 1 cmd or multiple cmd

Comment: would you explain to me how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for finding all of these in one go ? that is not possible ollydbg search is not text grep  copy paste the disassembly to text and use grep

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump                             Command         
00743F61      00                               DB      00
00743F62      00                               DB      00
00743F63      3E:C785 80000000 03000000        MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F6E      3E:66:C785 80000000 0300         MOV     WORD PTR DS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F78      3E:C685 80000000 03              MOV     BYTE PTR DS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F80      3E:FFB5 80000000                 PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+80]
00743F87      FFB0 80000000                    PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+80]
00743F8D      36:8180 80000000 FF000000        ADD     DWORD PTR SS:[EAX+80], 0FF
00743F98      0000                             ADD     BYTE PTR DS:[EAX], AL
00743F9A      0000                             ADD     BYTE PTR DS:[EAX], AL
```

but if you are looking for finding all one kind of instruction
like let's say

push dword ptr anyseg:[ANY register +SOMECONST]  (the keyword being the mnemonic)   or

mov dword ptr ANYSEG:[ANYREGISTER + SOMECONST]  (again it is mov that drives the search not the operand

then it is possible   either **ctrl+f  and type  PUSH [R32+CONST]**

or **right click search for all commands and type push [r32+CONST]**

the search for PUSH [R32+CONST] yields ~4500 hits  whereas PUSH [eax+80] yields one hit

```
>wc -l search.txt
4581 search.txt

>grep -i +80 search.txt | wc -l
19

>grep -i EAX+80 search.txt | wc -l
1

>grep -i EAX+80 search.txt
00743F87  PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+80]

>grep -i EbX+80 search.txt | wc -l
0

>grep -i ECX+80 search.txt | wc -l
1

>grep -i ECX+80 search.txt
00728460  PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+80]
```

here is another example

searching for `mov [r32+CONST] , CONST`

```
:\>wc -l srch.txt
925 srch.txt

:\>head -n 3 srch.txt
Search - Commands found in calc:.text
Address   Command                                  Comments
006F16F1  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-0CF0], 30

:\>tail -n 3 srch.txt
00743F70  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+80], C63E0003
00743F78  MOV     BYTE PTR DS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F79  MOV     BYTE PTR SS:[EBP+80], 3

:\>grep -i 80 srch.txt | wc -l
54

:\>grep -i ebp+80 srch.txt | wc -l
7

:\>grep -i ebp+80 srch.txt
00743F63  MOV     DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F64  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F6E  MOV     WORD PTR DS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F6F  MOV     WORD PTR SS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F70  MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+80], C63E0003
00743F78  MOV     BYTE PTR DS:[EBP+80], 3
00743F79  MOV     BYTE PTR SS:[EBP+80], 3
```